# Can't run apt-get update in an Ubuntu 16.04 docker container

Tags: docker, linux, ubuntu

Everytime I run `apt-get update -y` in my Ubuntu 16.04 docker container, I get the following error:

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu16.04/amd64  InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:5 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/experimental/ubuntu16.04/amd64  InRelease
Hit:6 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/experimental/ubuntu16.04/amd64  InRelease
Ign:7 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  InRelease
Ign:8 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  InRelease
Ign:9 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Ign:11 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Release
Ign:12 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Release
Ign:13 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Release
Ign:14 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
Ign:15 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
Ign:16 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
Ign:14 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
Ign:15 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
Ign:16 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
Ign:14 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
Ign:15 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
Ign:16 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
Ign:14 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
Ign:15 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
Ign:16 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
Ign:14 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
Ign:15 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
Ign:16 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
Ign:14 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
Ign:15 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
Ign:16 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
Err:14 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:15 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:16 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Packages
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libnvidia-container.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-runtime.list:1
W: The repository 'https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu16.04/x86_64  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/ubuntu16.04/x86_64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/ubuntu16.04/x86_64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu16.04/x86_64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This is my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list`:

```
deb https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/ubuntu16.04/x86_64 /
deb https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/ubuntu16.04/x86_64 /
deb https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu16.04/x86_64 /
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is because ubuntu16 is no longer supported by Nvidia

They have shut this repo down

visiting the error page shows they have marked it as unsupported
https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/ubuntu16.04/x86_64

check out the below for supported versions
https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/